# Unwanted page break in SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have an RDL report built in Business Intelligence Studio 2008 and I am having an issue with an unwanted page break.

I have a single dataset with a singletable with some summed data.  I have added in a List and added two groups.

[image]

I have even checked the page break properties of each one.

[image]

[image]

The report works fine, but my top most group seems to page breaking, leaving extra pages in the beginning.

What I would like to happen is to have the top most group be a page header, and the second group to be a group header for the detail.  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: As @Bactos mentioned it this is most probably because of the `White spaces` but If you just Want grouping then why did you included List ? By just simple looking at it can be done by the help of only `tablix ` no need for the List.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some things you can look at...

- Check your report Properties - Look at Consume Container WhiteSpace >
  Set it to True
- It looks like you are checking the Tablix page break. Did you right
  click on each of the Row Group > Group Properties > Page Break
  Options Between Each Instance of a Group?
- Another issue could be the margins (make sure they are set to inches
  if that is what you use). Make sure that your Margins + Report body
  is less than the printing area you are attempting to print on
  (screen/pdf/paper/etc).
- Using '&' for string concatenation instead of '+' (don't know why but
  this sometimes causes page issues).
- Check can grow settings on your cells
- Print destinations settings > properties > check "Override Default settings"
- Check the white space around your report body (attempt to minimize any if you can)
  Here is some other useful info about [Pagination](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255278(v=sql.105).aspx) from MS SQL Server

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that my margins were off.

Comment: I had a field of type char(5000) and that was what caused the page break. Trimming it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a tablix with "Keep Together" marked. The tablix also showed a subreport for each row.  It turned out that the first record had a very long subreport so it could not fit on the page w/ the top of page elements I had (report title).

this took me the better part of an afternoon before I realized what was happening. 
ultimately i lived with it. I wanted the keep together feature.  Next week, a shorter record will be the first one and it wont be an issue.